# plot cv2 with tkinter in python3 method

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, opencv, python

I´m trying to see in button event processed images. I´m using tkinter slider component to setup cv2 bitwise properties. All works fine when plot outside but I would like to see inside a tk root frame.

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlopen
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)    
  
def event(): 
    url = "http://image.jpg"
    req = urlopen(url)
    arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  
    
    red_low = (int(slider_lowerH.get()), int(slider_lowerS.get()), int(slider_lowerV.get()))
    red_high = (int(slider_higherH.get()), int(slider_higherS.get()), int(slider_higherV.get()))
   

    mask_red = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_low, red_high)

    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask = mask_red)
    
    #ERROR PLOTING IN TK!!!
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 5))
    fig.add_subplot(111).plot(plt.imshow(res))  
    #fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 5))   
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self.master)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: Try `ax = fig.add_subplot(111); ax.imshow(res)` instead of `fig.add_subplot(111).plot(plt.imshow(res))`.

Comment: great! this change in code works properly